# Stack usage on function call and stack reuse

Tags: c, optimization

I'm working on a IoT project, where memory management is important.

I am encountering a stack usage problem : if a function (or Statement expression  or Lambda) returning a structure is called directly as a argument of another function, a new structure is added on the stack and memory is not reused.

The example code below adds 4 structure to the stack

```
struct TestStruct
{
    uint32_t field1;
    uint32_t field2;
    uint32_t field3;
    uint32_t field4;
} ;

struct TestStruct initStructure(uint32_t f1, uint32_t f2, uint32_t f3, uint32_t f4)
{
    struct TestStruct myStruct;
    myStruct.field1 = f1;
    myStruct.field2 = f2;
    myStruct.field3 = f3;
    myStruct.field4 = f4;
    return myStruct;
}

void doStuff(struct TestStruct myStruct)
{
    printf("f1 = %d, f2 = %d, f3 = %d, f4 = %d", myStruct.field1, myStruct.field2, myStruct.field3, myStruct.field4);
}

int main(void)
{
    doStuff(initStructure(1,2,3,4));
    doStuff(initStructure(11,22,33,44));
    doStuff(initStructure(11,12,13,14));
    doStuff(initStructure(21,22,23,24));
}
```

I would have thought that as the structure would behave like automatic temporary variables in separate scopes, memory would have been reused. Adding scopes around each function call does nothing, so the structure are reserved on the stack when you enter the main function.

I am using ARM GCC and this happens with -fstack-reuse=all and -Os, -Og, -O1, -O2. is there a way to force stack reuse on these variables ?

Thanks

Update : As it happens, our work environment was set up to use `-x c++` not matter what, and this is what cause the stack issues. It seems c++14 and c++17 are not really aggressive about stack reuse and that is an issue for us.

Another point is that the above code does behave like I explain on our environment, but not on a clean one. To observe the stack problems, the `initStructure` function can be modified as follows :

```
struct TestStruct initStructure(uint32_t f1, uint32_t f2, uint32_t f3, uint32_t f4)
{
    struct TestStruct myStruct;
    myStruct.field1 = f1;
    myStruct.field2 = f2;
    myStruct.field3 = f3;
    myStruct.field4 = f4;

    printf("Temporary address %x", &myStruct);
    return myStruct;
}
```

Without `-x c++` the stack is reused, but with it, the stack is not reused.

Why can't c++ reuse the stack ? We use some very interesting string calculations at compile time that is not available in C so it is very important for us to have both string manipulation and memory optimization.

Comment: You can initialize a structure like this: `struct TestStruct s {1,2,3,4};`

Comment: It looks like you use a C++ compiler to compile C.

Comment: Include the version of ARM gcc you're using, btw.

Comment: You could pass an output parameter (`struct TestStruct *s`) to the function, and return `void`.

Comment: @super Actually, `s = (struct TestStruct){1, 2, 3, 4};`.

Comment: We use arm-none-eabi-gcc (version gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2018-q4-major)

Comment: The goal is to use macro to generate some initialization macro, I'm more interested in why the stack is not reused, and not really interested in how to change the code. This is just example code to replicate the problem.

Comment: [ARM GC 8.2 with -O2](https://godbolt.org/z/lZSv27) shows `main` using just eight bytes of stack after pushing LR. The calls to `doStuff` and `initStructure` have been optimized away. What version of GCC are you using? What makes you think it is add four structures to the stack separately and not reusing stack space?

Comment: Were the compiler behaving as you report, the structure uses could be isolated in a separate function: `static void Separate(uint32_t f1, uint32_t f2, uint32_t f3, uint32_t f4) { doStuff(initStructure(f1, f2, f3, f4)); }`, followed by changing `main` to have four calls to `Separate(…)` instead of `doStuff(initStructure(…))`.

Comment: I'm using the static stack analyzer of Ozone and Visual studio to determine the stack used. Using -O2 does not reduce stack usage on my end, and the myStruct structure in the initStructure does not share the same address, but the ones in doStuff do share the same address, so the memory is reused in doStuff but not in initStructure.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You were right when saying everything was optimized away. Our environment was making me see the problem but you could not with a clean one. The updated sectoin should show the problem now

Comment: @wildplasser Indeed it look like it is a c++ compiler problem, any idea on why it is less optimized ?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/W5JRA8). Besides, not knowing what language you are using is probably more worrisome than some puny stack inefficiency.

Comment: Our project uses 90% C and 10% c++ (only for compile time computations), and the section that cause memory issues is pure C (like a good 20% stack not being reused), but compiled with a c++ compiler. Here is a link to reproduce the issue  : https://godbolt.org/z/aaMPbU

Comment: "pure C .... compiled with a C++ compiler". There is no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code should look more something like this. Pass structures by pointer, this way, you do not copy all the structure into the stack, only its' address. In your case, when you call `doStuff(initStructure(1,2,3,4))` you have 3 copied structures in the stack at same time.
Funciton `initStructure()` reserves memory in the stack for 2 structures since you declared its' return type as a structure and you created another local structure inside the function. Funciton `doStuff` allocates 1 structure in the stack for the parameter you pass to it. Pass by pointer would be more optimal by performance too since you don't need to allocate so much memory on the stack by calling the functions.

```
typedef struct 
{
    uint32_t field1;
    uint32_t field2;
    uint32_t field3;
    uint32_t field4;
}TestStruct;

TestStruct myStruct;

void initStructure(uint32_t f1, uint32_t f2, uint32_t f3, uint32_t f4, TestStruct* myStruct)
{
    //struct TestStruct myStruct;
    myStruct->field1 = f1;
    myStruct->field2 = f2;
    myStruct->field3 = f3;
    myStruct->field4 = f4;
    //return &myStruct;
}

void doStuff(TestStruct* myStruct)
{
    printf("f1 = %d, f2 = %d, f3 = %d, f4 = %d", myStruct->field1, myStruct->field2, myStruct->field3, myStruct->field4);
}

int main(void)
{
    initStructure(1,2,3,6,&myStruct);
    doStuff(&myStruct);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have tested this solution and it works fine, but we are stuck for the moment  with passing structure by copy for security reasons (less possibilities to access leftover data if you initialize a new structure each time and erase its previous content). We might have to chance this if we cannot reuse memory, and erase manually the content of the pointed structure.

Comment: @BaptisteC Try to use packed structures `struct __attribute__((packed))`. It is performance not friendly but you get rid of the bit padding in the structure and save some space, unless you structure is the same as in your example then that won't help because there are no padding.